# Python 3 "Sideways" Relative Import

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, relative-path, relative-import

I have a file structure like

```
math/
    snippets/
        numerical_methods.py
    homework1/
        main.py
    homework2/
        main.py
```

And in homework 1's main.py, I would like to do

```
from ..snippets.numerical_methods import fixed-point-iteration
```

So that I do not have to re-write this algorithm for every assignment I use it in. But I'm getting the error "Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't import from something higher up in the hierarchy than your main script, i.e. something higher up than the `homework1` folder. What you can do is add the path to the script you want to the import path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from snippets.numerical_methods import fixed-point-iteration
```

Comment: *You can't import from something higher up in the hierarchy than your script* - Actually you can...

Comment: See examples from [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) page ("Intra-package References" section)

Comment: Ease up on the downvotes folks. You can't import higher up than your *main* script. From the link: "Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current module. Since the name of the main module is always "`__main__`", modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application must always use absolute imports." I edited the answer to make that clearer.